# too many sessionid files in /tmp

Tags: apache, haproxy, sessionid

I have too many sessionid files in /tmp. The owner of those files is apache.
I have haproxy installed and I found that the timestamp interval of those files are exactly the same as the check interval configured in /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.
If I change the check interval of haproxy, the timestamp interval of the sessionid files changes also.

The sessionid files are like this.

sessionid3d7be1fb5875a41cd49bd1191a8aefe7  sessionid7f266a3a7bfe756d2ee831b835d29257  sessionidbf5fb4e84881fa7baa81842cb9e69c88  sessionidffb2626e8b475bafdf3e7f118902bda1
sessionid3d7d74e4c6cdbd31097e4e1160b26b7e  sessionid7f278beec39256a744f36d14bc3aa43f  sessionidbf655034560ee743459fa1eaa42fb5e3  sessionidffb294fa98a23798872cf3b4455ab2cc
sessionid3d7e15b22b1cf5f74e3fc9f7d93333aa  sessionid7f27b0eac3d9331c11304587511e729d  sessionidbf666b1da1199b201e7e782dad6c4396  sessionidffb7c43bca8adfb682c46e50ee00b705
sessionid3d7eee673420ca47c0fecd83e65c4140  sessionid7f28b6df0bc3b04df4361c4d5370c047  sessionidbf67268c0e7aef3d25fe66d904d1da61  sessionidffb9e086d254c277fc1e054417b802fd

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by openstack-dashboard.
I have SESSION_ENGIN configured as django.contrib.sessions.backends.file
After I changed it to django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache, no more sessionid files